# Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have spring boot mvc with a little jpa back for training in this system.
I have stylese with connected via thymeleaf links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" data-th-href="@{/bs/dist/css/bootstrap.css}">
<link rel="stylesheet" data-th-href="@{/htmlElements/myElements.css}">
```

this is my project structure

[image: project structure]
    Yesterday everything was working fine, but today I don't see my styles at all. After some researches I get this data:

1. direct link to http://localhost:8080/htmlElements/myElements.css do not response.
2. next I restarted my app with DEBUG enabled, and saw that

   2018-06-03 12:52:42.957 DEBUG 10888 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/bs/dist/css/bootstrap.css]
   2018-06-03 12:52:42.957 DEBUG 10888 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /bs/dist/css/bootstrap.css
   2018-06-03 12:52:42.958 DEBUG 10888 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1298ec89
   2018-06-03 12:52:42.958 DEBUG 10888 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/htmlElements/myElements.css]
   2018-06-03 12:52:42.958 DEBUG 10888 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /htmlElements/myElements.css
   2018-06-03 12:52:42.963 DEBUG 10888 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
   2018-06-03 12:52:42.963 DEBUG 10888 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
   2018-06-03 12:52:42.963 DEBUG 10888 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
   2018-06-03 12:52:42.963 DEBUG 10888 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
   2018-06-03 12:52:42.964 DEBUG 10888 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
   2018-06-03 12:52:42.964  WARN 10888 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'GET' not supported
   2018-06-03 12:52:42.964 DEBUG 10888 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
   2018-06-03 12:52:42.964  WARN 10888 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'GET' not supported
   2018-06-03 12:52:42.964 DEBUG 10888 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
   2018-06-03 12:52:42.964 DEBUG 10888 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling

So, i can't understand what the matter. I do not touch any spring boot autoconfig things. 
I think i should reconfigure WebMvcConfigurer.class with addResourceHandlers() its method, but i cant find correct guide how to realise it with spring boot.

I can make css like usual @GetMapping with proper position at "/templates", but it bad idea?

UPDATE | PARTIALLY SOLVED
i found 1 contoller with @PostMapping without value. Remove it.Restart - styles appears. Then I add this @PostMapping() to the method of @Controller class and do not see those bug. So if anyone get the same problem: restart ide -> then check ur controllers.
thx 4 help guys

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the resource files like CSS etc the you should add configuration for it in you configuration class, to redirect such request to show the files content.

Currently there is no mapping for request. try adding below code in Configuration.java file that is annotated with @Configuration .

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/web/static/css/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/web/static/js/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/web/static/images/");
}
```

Please map the file location in the above code as per your path.

Comment: But I havn't web inf in my project. Will it correctly work with templates and resource folders wich uses in default spring boot mvc project?

Comment: replace WEB-INF with resource, or the folder that you have.